# Number of parameters of genus 5 curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I want to show that up to automorphisms, the number of parameters of the intersection of three general quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$ is exactly $12$. I want to do it using the tools of chapter $7$ by Miranda and no schemes.

My idea is: we have 24 parameters describing automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^4$ and $\binom{6}{2}=15$. So $24-15=9$ and we can fix one of these quadrics. How can I complete the proof?

Comment: Here is a hint: By Bertini's theorem, 3 general quadrics intersect in a smooth curve $C$ in $\mathbb{P}^4$. You can compute the canonical bundle of $C$ by adjunction. Do it and see what you get...